# Search string for values in array

Tags: php

I have address fetched from MySQL like :

```
$address="This Street, Nice Area, That Country";
$address="This Street, Superb Area, Which Country";
$address="This Street, Fine Area, A Country";
```

Now what I am trying to do is find AREA - which is like `$area=array("Nice", "Good")`. So if value defined in `$area` is found in `$address` it should list or else leave blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$area=array(1=>"Nice", "Good");
$address = 'This Street, Nice Area, That Country';
preg_match(', (\w+) Area,', $address, $res);
$is_area = array_search( $res[1], $area, true) ;
if($is_area) echo $address;
```

**Explanation**

first line sets the array of areas to start with index 1 rather than zero ( makes sure the lookup does not return zero)

the preg_match line extracts the area from the address

the array search line looks up the area in your array of areas

Comment: _“( makes sure the lookup does not return zero)”_ – rather then “meddling” with the input data, you could just check the `array_search` result against `!== false` in your if condition.

Comment: Thanks for quick help - But I had small mistake in my question. In Address we may not have any identical values - it can be like time square, wall street, central park etc. Sorry for my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking can be paraphrased as:

"*List all $address strings that contain an instance of a string found in the `$area` array.*"

In which case:

```
// Set up.
$address = array(
    "This Street, Nice Area, That Country",
    "This Street, Superb Area, Which Country",
    "This Street, Fine Area, A Country",
);
$area = array("Nice", "Good");

// The search.
$results = array();
foreach ($address as $haystack) {
    foreach ($area as $needle) {
        $regexPattern = "#{$needle}#";
        if (preg_match($regexPattern, $haystack)) 
            array_push($results, $haystack);
    }
}

// The results.
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo "<p>{$result}</p>";
}
```